Conceptual doubt in existence of normal force in a constrained motion problem
I was solving a problem on Wedge-constrained motion. Given below is it's diagram.

This system is released from rest. All surfaces are assumed to be frictionless and string is inextensible.
I have drawn a free-body diagram showing the forces acting on the blocks below:

My analysis:

Block B would move downwards in the cavity of wedge C

The string will get taut and the tension acting on the pulley will accelerate the wedge rightwards as the pulley is connected to the wedge C. The tension on the pulley also acts vertically downwards but the wedge can't penetrate the surface and move down.

Block B moves in x and y directions with accelerations $a_{Bx}$ and $a_{By}$ as shown in the figure above.

As block B is in contact with wedge C, the acceleration of the wedge along the x-axis is equal to the acceleration of B along the x-axis. So, we have $\color{blue}{a_{Bx} = a_{Cx}}$

Both the junctions $P_1$ and $P_2$ the wedge C and block B are in contact. So, the acceleration of block C and points $P_1$ and $P_2$ must be the same to avoid penetration.

So, in this case at points $P_1$ and $P_2$ there is no pressing between the wedge C as both the junctions and the wedge C have the same acceleration. So, normal force won't exist


My Doubt:
I'm aware that normal force arises when two surfaces press each other and merely being in contact doesn't require normal contact force to exist. So, in this case, would there be two different normal forces (say $N_1$ and $N_2$) to take into account? Or is the normal force zero at both the junctions $P_1$ and $P_2$?

If block B has mass and is accelerating to the right it must have a force to the right acting on it.

Yeah, it's true but it doesn't explain why there would be normal contact force on the junction P2 as well?

@BobD So, no normal forces at P1 and P2?

Without me answering the question, you have to decide whether or not the green object accelerates or not. If you think that it does accelerate then you have to decide which force(s) cause the acceleration.

@Farcher Forgot about the force of the pulley on C. Thanks.

As Farcher noted in the comments, there must be a horizontal force acting on $B$ if it is to accelerate horizontally.  So there must be a force acting at least one of the points $P_1$ or $P_2$.
There can, in principle, be forces at both points $P_1$ and $P_2$.  However, both of them will enter into Newton's Second Law in the same way:  they will provide an force on block $B$ and a corresponding reaction force on block $C$.  This means that when you write out the equations for Newton's Second Law, you won't be able to solve individually for the normal forces $N_{BC1}$ and $N_{BC2}$, since they enter into the equations in exactly the same way.  You'll only be able to solve for a combination of the two (either $N_{BC1} + N_{BC2}$ or $N_{BC1} - N_{BC2}$, depending on how you define your directions.)
So in the end, it is more expedient to just define $N_{BC}$ to be this combination of contact forces.  This combination represents the net horizontal force on $B$ from $C$; and this net force is all that Newton's Laws in themselves can tell you about.

As @ Farcher says there is a force that you have not drawn. The tension acts on the  on the pully of $|F|= sqrt{2}T$  directed at 45 degrees below the horizonal. It has a horizontal component of $T$ acting on the big block through the yellow sloping support. .
